# Iterating through existing list values while creating it with a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

while this is completely not needed I still want to try and put everything I can in as little lines of code as possible while also using OOP

I have the code done without OOP but someone asked whether it can be done with OOP, the problem can be solved in more lines of code but I want to put as much into just 1 as possible

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z,a):
        self.id = x
        self.prompt = y
        self.score = z
        self.overall_scores = a

players = [Player(x,y,random.randint(1,6),{z.id:z.score for z in players} 
if x == 3 else None) for x,y in zip(range(0,4),["First", "Second", "Third", 
"Fourth"])]
```

I expect to have each player with their own score and last player to hold the overall scores so that I could sort them by their value to determine the player with the highest score. Note that OOP is not the best way to approach this task but I was asked how it would look with OOP

What the program should do: each player is given a random score and then ranked based on the highest score

Edit:
Since the code without OOP was requested, here it is:

```
import operator,random

players = {x:0 for x in range(0,4)}
prompts = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]

for a in players:
    players[a] = random.randint(1,6)
    print("%s:\nDice: %s" % (prompts[a],players[a]))
sorted_players = sorted(players.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))

draw = True
previous = 0
draw_between = []
first = True
for a in sorted_players[::-1]:
    if first:
        previous = a[1]
        first = False
    elif previous != a[1]:
        draw = False
    if draw:
        draw_between.append(a[0])

if draw:
    print("The chances of this were astronomically low but it happened anyway!")
    print("It's a draw!")
elif len(draw_between) <= 1:
    print("%s Player Wins!" % (prompts[sorted_players[-1][0]]))
else:
    out = "First place is a draw between Players:\n"
    draw_between.sort()
    for b,a in enumerate(draw_between):
        out += str(prompts[a])
        if b < len(draw_between)-1:
            out += ", "
    print(out)
```

Comment: oh well, so much for readability and human friendly code.

Comment: yeah it's definitely not very readable but its concise

Comment: dont u think this wil give error when players has None ?

Comment: it gives an error because it can't iterate through the list while it's creating it. The only attribute of Player that can be None is the overall_scores which I'm not using

Comment: i think it's better to post the code without oops which is working and then ask for code in this way

Comment: "I'm making my code unreadable on purpose! Here, read it!"

Comment: yeah I'm sorry to subject you to my unreadable code but I'm writing it with the least amount of lines possible

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Actually, I don't even see one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments and the end of the question indicate, you do not need the "overall score" as well as you do not need to collect the score of the last player. If that is the case, then this does what you want, i.e. "each player is given a random score and then ranked based on the highest score" (I assumed you wanted them ranked from first to last):

```
import random


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.id = x
        self.prompt = y
        self.score = z


players = [Player(x,
                  y,
                  random.randint(1, 6))
           for x, y in zip(range(0, 4), ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"])]

sorted_players = sorted([Player(x,
                                y,
                                random.randint(1, 6))
                         for x, y in zip(range(0, 4), ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"])], 
                        key=lambda dude: dude.score, reverse=True)
```